# How to remove the limit for outputting to windows console (cmd)

Tags: python, console

I am working on a text renderer in python which outputs to the console and I have realized that higher resolutions such as 128x128 cannot be achieved as there seems to be a 64 line limit in a single string. Is there any way to disable this?

*(I am writing the output to the console buffer so I cannot split the output into 2 parts
)*

Comment: Create a shortcut to cmd.exe on your desktop and then right-click on it and select "Properties" from the pop-out menu. In the dialog that appears there's "Layout" tab, select that and in the settings shown you can change the default Screen buffer and Window sizes. You can set all to very high values. Afterwards click on "OK" to exit and save your changes.

Comment: welp this just made this worse whatevs

Comment: I forgot to mention that after creating the shortcut, you have to *use* it to start the Windows console. I thought that would be obvious — but now, not so much…

Comment: i did... i used the shortcut. I thought that was obvious

Comment: I've used the technique for years and know that it does work.

Comment: thanks for trying to help anyways!